# MySQL query not going away after being killed

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL query that is copying data from one table to another for processing. For some reason, this query that normally takes a few seconds locked up overnight and ran for several hours. When I logged in this morning, I tried to kill the query, but it is still listed in the process list.

```
| Id      | User     | Host      | db   | Command | Time  | State        | Info                                                                                 |
+---------+----------+-----------+------+---------+-------+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1061763 | tb_admin | localhost | dw   | Killed  | 45299 | Sending data | INSERT INTO email_data_inno_stage SELECT * FROM email_data_test LIMIT 4480000, 10000 |
| 1062614 | tb_admin | localhost | dw   | Killed  |   863 | Sending data | INSERT INTO email_data_inno_stage SELECT * FROM email_data_test LIMIT 4480000, 10000 |
```

What could have caused this, and how can I kill this process so I can get on with my work?

Comment: Bouncing mysql would clear that up, if you want to go for the nuclear option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the table email_data_test is MyISAM and it was locked, that would have held up the the INSERT.

If the table email_data_test is InnoDB, then a lot of MVCC data was being written in ib_logfiles, which may not have occurred yet.

In both cases, you had the LIMIT clause scroll through 4,480,000 rows just to get to 10,000 rows you actually needed to INSERT.

Killing the query only causes the InnoDB table email_data_inno_stage to execute a rollback.

Comment: Thanks. The table is innodb. I know this might not be an ideal way to do this, but if I processed the entire email_data_test table of 70 million records it would take forever, if the database could even handle it, so I had it doing it as batches of 10k records.

Comment: I actually had a similar issue, but mine was a `select count(*) query.` After I killed it it showing still showing in processlist. from innodb_trx the trx operation status was Countng Reads. Any idea why its getting stuck?  The strange thing is its on this same state from past 1 month :)

Comment: @TheDataGuy were you been able to solve that? What was the reason?