# Process that was killed still on my processlist

Tags: mysql

The thread that I killed is still on my thread list How do I eliminate it?

```
+-----+------+-----------+-------------+---------+-------+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Id  | User | Host      | db          | Command | Time  | State     | Info                                                                                                 |
+-----+------+-----------+-------------+---------+-------+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 678 | root | localhost | hthtthv     | Killed  | 36923 | query end | INSERT INTO `gtgttg` VALUES (1,'tgtg'),(2,'Shopping'),(4,'tgtgtg'),(          |
| 695 | root | localhost | NULL        | Query   |     0 | NULL      | show processlist                                                                                     |
+-----+------+-----------+-------------+---------+-------+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL query not going away after being killed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5043268/mysql-query-not-going-away-after-being-killed)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It needs to revert the actions it did, so this can take a long time. If it is an INNODB database, you can for instance look at this question: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5654/internal-reason-for-killing-process-taking-up-long-time-in-mysql

So in the end: you need to wait for it to be eliminated

Comment: That depends on your query, the amount of results, your hardware, your software, you horoscope and the weather ;) .. aka, hard to say. For instance, with INNODB it can take way longer then the insert was doing. Check that first answer: longer means "up to 30 times"....

Comment: I ran original query for 8 hours. Does that mean it could take 240 hours?  I  am using an innodb database. There is no other practical way to kill this query?

Comment: DId you read the question I linked and the answer? I had this discussion with the person who answered it, and I ended up just killing the server.

Comment: When I do a kill -9 it shows me an error message ERROR 1094 (HY000): Unknown thread id: 18446744073709551607

Comment: i have skip-log-bin still its been 1 hour plus and status shows as query end. why is that ?

Comment: As far as I know above issue does not have anything to do with the bin log, so... the same answer?

Answer (score 5):

In my case, my /var partition was full, where the MySQL binlogs are written. Once I freed some disk space, the killed connections immediately went away.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question. I faced a similar situation, where the thread was stuck in killed status.

Instead of forcibly killing the mysqld, I issued

```
sudo service stop mysqld
```

The command could different depending on your OS, but you need to gracefully ask the system to terminate the daemon. It will kill the stuck thread and there will be no side effects on the database as it will be a normal shutdown.

Other suggestion above asked to kill the process, which will lead to database recovery which could have its own issues. So I would recommend going with the daemon graceful stop.

Hope that helps.