# Why do I need to rollback a SELECT in mysql (InnoDB)?

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb, sql-optimization

I ran an ill-advised `SELECT *` on a large InnoDB table in a mysql database.

So after 10 minutes or so I realised the error, found the `connectionid` with show processlist, and attempted to kill both the connection and the query with the kill command.  Then I ran another query on the same table.

`show processlist` shows the original select to have received the Killed flag, but is stuck in the "Sending data" state.  The followup query is waiting for a lock.  This has been going on for several hours.

Now I understand why, if my original query had been modifying the table in any way, that what I'd be describing would be waiting for the rollback.

But this was a `select`; what would it even mean to rollback a select ?

So I wondered if anyone could tell me what I'm waiting for, and if there are any convenient ways to just cancel a `select` query.

Comment: Question may be already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5043268/mysql-query-not-going-away-after-being-killed

Comment: "If the table email_data_test is InnoDB, then a lot of MVCC data was being written in ib_logfiles, which may not have occurred yet."

Comment: Thanks for the link; that's not one of the examples I found in my pre-post search, but it's similar to the ones I did find.  The explanation they give in that thread for why it takes so long to kill - as apart from why the original query was taking so long in the first place - was "Killing the query only causes the InnoDB table email_data_inno_stage to execute a rollback."  Which is just back to my original question: why would I need to rollback a select?

Comment: (Which, in retrospect, would have made a much better title for my original question.)

Comment: Enough so that I edited the title of the post.  I hope that doesn't make this question hard to track for anyone, but I found a few posts on meta-SO that seemed to state that it was worth doing if you came up with a better title.  Certainly feel free to change it back if that's inappropriate, or you think the new title is worse.  (Specifically, I think this one is better because it distinguishes this question from a number which have already been answered on SO, but which were about INSERT / DELETES, where a rollback would be perfectly sensible.)

Comment: You don't need to rollback a SELECT.  Just because terminating a write-query can often cause a long wait time while the database rolls back does not mean that a long wait time after terminating a read-query is also due to a rollback.  It sounds like there's something else going on.

Comment: @JimmyT. -- That other entry was about INSERTs being stuck.  This is about SELECTs; there is a big difference since a SELECT should not have anything to "ROLLBACK".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not waiting for a transaction rollback, as others have said. I also have encountered this problem: call it a bug because it is one really though MySQL do not agree.

Now I can not give you anything but an educated guess for the reason you get this 'deadlock', but I can give you a solution:

UNLOCK TABLES  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html